# IOException: Cannot run program "python"

Tags: java, python

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","/Users/puja/Downloads/test.py");

Process proc = null;
try {
    proc = pb.start();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String s;
    while ((s = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Puja : " + s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It gives an error:

```
System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=13, Permission denied while trying to excute .py file
```

**Though I got an answer but it did not help me. Please provide me a solution to resolve this error**.

Comment: i thing it's permission issue, try to change permission and add shebang at start of you python script, it might fix it.

Comment: changed SDK folder permission (sudo chmod -R 777 ./sdk/). but did not work. @AshishSharma

Comment: change it for the folder containing python file

Comment: given permission containing python file..getting same error. @AshishSharma

Comment: try to run the program as sudo user

Comment: Did it..not worked @SUJITKUMARSINGH

Comment: Did you get the same error? If not please post that error.

Comment: same error @SUJITKUMARSINGH